# liquibase - Alter Table Add Column - is it safe to add varchar column in between

Tags: liquibase

What is the internal behavior of liquibase when adding a column within existing columns and the table is in production which has millions of rows.

is it same behavior if a column is added at the end?

Instead of varchar if a column is numeric, then what is the behvaior?

Answer (score 1):

Use updateSql instead of update command to see what query is generated by liquibase. How this query is handled later depends on your database.